# MaterialUI TextField select with text-tranform

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've got the following code where I try to capitalize the values shown as labels inside MenuItem but does not apply the text transformation. Any ideas?

```
const values = ['some value', 'some value 2'];

<TextField
    id="status"
    name="status"
    select
    label="Status"
    onChange={this.handleSearch}
    value={filter.status}
    className={classes.textField}
>
    {campaignStatus.map(status => (
        <MenuItem key={status} value={status} style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
            {status}
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</TextField>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because material ui has their own system of overriding styles, you have to use this syntax

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const Function = props => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    center: {
      textTransform: "capitalize"
    }
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();

  const values = ["some value", "some value 2"];

  return (
    <TextField
      id="status"
      name="status"
      select
      label="Status"
      onChange={this.handleSearch}
      value={filter.status}
      className={classes.textField}
    >
      {campaignStatus.map(status => (
        <MenuItem key={status} value={status} className={classes.center}>
          {status}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </TextField>
  );
};
```